# No debug information for SMTPDebug in PHPMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to show debug information but none is showing up on my html page :

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'src/Exception.php';
require 'src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'src/SMTP.php';

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
  $username = 'username@gmail.com';
  $password = 'MyPass';
  $to = $username;
  $mail = new PHPMailer();
  $mail->IsSMTP();
  $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
  $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
  $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
  $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
  $mail->Port = 465;

  $mail->IsHTML(true);
  $mail->Username = $username;
  $mail->Password = $password;
  $mail->SetFrom($_POST["contactName"." "."contactEmail"]);
  $mail->Subject = $_POST["contactSubject"];
  $mail->Body = $_POST["contactMessage"];
  $mail->AddAddress($to);


  if(!$mail->Send())
  {
    echo "Mailer error : " . $mail->ErrorInfo . "<br>";
  }
}
```

Actually i only get an empty div, the error div is called but nothing is showed in it

What must I change to see that error appearing?
I looked at wiki and my code seems to be correct.

Comment: How are you sure, that there is an error? Add an else branch to show a success message.

Comment: Is this really accurate: `$_POST["contactName"." "."contactEmail"]`? That's the same as doing: `$_POST["contactName contactEmail"]`. Do you actually have a form element with that name? Check your servers error log.

Comment: Though you're using a recent PHPMailer, you've based your code on an obsolete example. You're forging the from address - don't do that; use your own address as the from address and add the submitter's address as a reply-to. Neither of these fix the problem you posted about - I'd guess that the code is not being run at all.

Comment: Exactly my code doesn't got executed cause after adding an else statement it's that statement which is called

Comment: it's like there's no post data but in the network tab there's some stuff that says everything's ok : https://imgur.com/1NNAFoM

Comment: I changed my code and it still doesn't get any data, could the problem come from my html form ?

Comment: My php code looks like this : http://codepad.org/oG4W63Bo   and my html form like this : https://jsfiddle.net/h5ndm7L2/